# Custom Devise User not authorized for Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a custom user like such:

```
class PersonsController < UsersController

end
```

However, after signing in just fine, when I click "persons/edit", I get redirected to the login page...  I can see in the logs the following:

> Processing by Person::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML Completed
>   401 Unauthorized in 0ms

Then I get redirected to the Login page again, I didn't lose the session at this point, I could click back on my profile and see the account details.

Just not sure why Devise has issues with the Edit action

I also have the following structure in my registration controller

```
class Person
     class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
     end
end
```

Any help, it's appreciated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the solution, I had to redefine this method in my custom Person::RegistrationsController

```
def authenticate_scope!
  send(:"authenticate_user!", :force => true)
  self.resource = send(:"current_user")
end
```

It seems the session doesn't have a custom "current_person" method, but always a current_user because I'm login in with 'users/sign_in' (I wanted a common login point for other custom users in my system). If I login with 'persons/sign_in' then this workaround is not needed. For some reason. Im not really sure why, this was the original method from devise's github repo:

```
def authenticate_scope!
  send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", :force => true)
  self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
end
```

I hope this helps someone in the future, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your final goal of your custom devise it not clear, but if you are trying to edit the info of the current user i recommend you to check this link. [Devise - How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)

This example is to edit the user password, but if you require more fields you could add it without problems. But you should have a separate controller that uses the Users model.

Comment: hi Jorge, in this case, the user is actually logged in, the session is active, that's the weird thing, it's redirecting me as Unathorized when in fact the user has been authorized. The only difference here is that the user has inherited from UsersController. So not sure why it's not detecting the valid session